# Struts 1 Form submision

Tags: struts, struts-1, actionform

How to create Struts 1 form? i have created the app on struts 1 and completed the struts-config.xml and web.xml mapping i am also retrieving the values from the jsp.page but not sure what tag i need to use in form to capture them with javascript and submit the to action class. I have done lots of googling but can not find resources.

Done googling but can not find any resources on how to create struts 1 form and what tags i need to use to update the values with javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

this is my html code for struts.

```
 <td><html:select property="empId" styleId="empId"
                            onchange="getEmployee()">
                            <html:option value="">---None---</html:option>
                            <html:options property="employeeId" />
                        </html:select></td>
```

and i am using jquery and ajax so i think same for java script

```
    function getEmployee() {
        let empId = $('#empId').val();
       alart(empId);
}
```

and this is how you get id in ActionClass

```
 String id = request.getParameter("id");
        Long sId = 0L;
        if (id != null) {
            try {
                sId = Long.parseLong(id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
   System.out.println(sId );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're facing (although I'm not sure why you're working around the `ActionForm` abstraction).